# Android - How to get the assignment code of a variable from the watch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing unit tests and one of my classes constructor takes in parameters a very "complicated" one (very big array of maps, which values come from NFC tag).

I'd like to test this method and to use it, I need to make this array.

Is there a way to get it in debug mode from the watch and automagically get the corresponding assignment code.

*Example*:
In the watch: `myArray = {string[200]@123456789}`
Intended output: `"String[] myArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", ...}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution :

I simply made a `.toString()` on my ArrayList (in the Watches), and then I use the string in return to recreate the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In the watch panel : `right click on your variable > customize data view > Java Data Type renderer`. Then choose the class to render, click on `Use following expression` and write any expression as you where in a method of the class you are watching.

You can write a custom method that you call there like `toTestString()`

[image]